# Static function in Cpp file Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I generate the my source code with Doxygen,
Doxygen generate void and another fucntion but it didnt generate static function although `EXTRACT_STATIC` is YES.
I am currently using version of the `Doxygen 1.8.19`and
I added top of the example.cpp file `/** @file example.cpp */`
I am using .c and .cpp file together. In the example.cpp file I have:

```
/**
 *@brief ..
 *@param size  The application receives in this parameter the size of the required memory block.
 *@retval      The application must return a pointer to the allocated and zeroed-out memory block.
 */

static void* CheckVal (unsigned int size)
{
    void* result = malloc (size);
    assert (result != NULL);
    memset (result, 0, size);
    return result;
}
```

I couldnt see any function in doxygen index.html . Why this happened?

Comment: Please add at the top of the file `/** \file */`, doxygen doesn't always pickup the `.c` / `.cpp` files. Please always specify the doxygen version used.

Comment: I added some detail for my question

Comment: When I use your example I see on the "index.html" in the top blue bar "Main Page" "File", where "Files" has a drop down menu and from here I can get to "example.cpp" and the description of the function. Maube useful for you would be also to set "GENERATE_TREEVIEW=YES"

Comment: Which version do you have? Maybe problem because of version. ?

Comment: Before you ask the question about the version you should mention the subversion you are using, the platform you are running on and whether or not you compiled the executable yourself. I think the problem you have is independent of the version and platform).  I have all versions. But this test I ran with 1.8.18 and with the latest master (1.8.19 (3040df2f0aa29a4207de5b37da1d20e3d27340bb)).

Comment: @albert Doxywizard version 1.8.11 and my doxygen version is 1.8.19 . I understand Doxywizard not working correctly. Because I try the doxygen Doxyfile command in terminal it works. I have problem because of Doxywizard. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Strange that you are using the doxygen wizard 1.8.11 and doxygen version 1.8.19 how did this happen? Did you install the wizard a long time and recently only regenerated doxygen?

Comment: I dont know I think I remove all doxygen and install again :D

Comment: Might be a god idea so you know what you have.

Comment: Impossible to remove, I tried all remove command with this link https://installlion.com/ubuntu/xenial/main/d/doxygen/uninstall/index.html and again I have doxygen 1.8.19 like sticky :)

Comment: Strange that you have 1.8.19 as this is the current master version and has not been released yet, this would mean that somebody with administrator / root rights (or that doxygen is possible with sudo as allowed executable on your system) has installed a development version on your system. What is the full output of `doxygen -v` so we have the exact doxygen (1.8.19) version you have and we can see from where it is build. The date of the executable might give you some clues as well (please check with people with root rights on your system whether they know / did something).

Comment: I solve the problem I remove ./doxygen in usr/local/bin with sudo rm ./doxygen 
and than doxygen version become 1.8.11 and I run the wizard working correctly

Comment: So someone dropped a `doxygen` in your `/usr/local/bin` interesting that you got errors when the versions of the `doxywizard` and `doxygen` don't match, but as these errors are not revealed here it is not possible to comment on it.